# Amazon mws Signature Does not match

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am trying to connect to my Amazon MWS account using python requests. I defined the params for testing and calculated a signature from the query string.

My code :

```
cur_date = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
secret_key = 'my_secret_key'

sign_str = 'POST' + '\n' + 'mws.amazonservices.in' + '\n' + '/Orders/2013-09-01' + '\n' + 'AWSAccessKeyId=access_key&Action=ListOrders&LastUpdatedAfter=2015-10-31T18:30:00Z&MarketplaceId.Id.1=A21TJRUUN4KGV&SellerId=seller_id&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=%s&Version=2013-09-01' %cur_date

# I am using below method to generate a signature. I read about this in various threads and questions.

sign = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(str(secret_key), sign_str, hashlib.sha256).digest())

payload = {'AWSAccessKeyId':'access_key',
    'Action':'ListOrders',
    'MarketplaceId.Id.1':'A21TJRUUN4KGV',
    'SellerId':'seller_id',
    'Timestamp':cur_date,
    'SignatureMethod':'HmacSHA256',
    'Signature':sign,
    'SignatureVersion':2,
    'Version':'2013-09-01',
    'LastUpdatedAfter':'2015-10-31T18:30:00Z'}

url = 'https://mws.amazonservices.in/Orders/2013-09-01'
headers = {'Content-Type':'text/xml'}
resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params = payload)
```

And i get this in response:

```
<Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
</Error>
```

I know the problem is in how the signature is being generated.
I tested my credentials on MWS SCRATCHPAD and they are working fine.

What is correct method to generate a signature?

Comment: Probably won't matter here but you also need to make sure you replace the following characters ('+' with '%20' - '*' with '%2A' - '%7E' with '~') before submitting the request.

Comment: @Manish Gupta sorry for late comment, but you need to send the parameters in queryString not in params .Thanks